# PdfContentByte will not overwite a check box

Tags: c#, itext

I am adding content to an existing PDF using pdfContentByte.  The existing PDF document which was originally created in word has several check box.  I need to overlay an 'X' on the check box when appropriate.  What can I do to cause the 'X' to overlay the check box. With the code below the 'X' is placed under the checkbox.

```
  private static void AddField(float xpos, float ypos, string Text, PdfImportedPage page, PdfContentByte cb2, BaseFont f_cn2)
{
  cb2.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
  cb2.BeginText();
  cb2.SetFontAndSize(f_cn2, 10);
  cb2.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, Text, xpos, ypos, 0F);
  //cb2.SetTextMatrix(xpos, ypos);  //(xPos, yPos)
  //cb2.ShowText(Text);
  cb2.EndText();
}
```

Comment: in your title, do you mean _Override_ or _Overwrite_?

Answer (score 1):

If your check box is a form field, then it is visualized using a widget annotation. A widget annotation is a specific form of annotation. Annotations are interactive features that aren't part of the content stream of a page. They are listed in the `/Annots` array of the page dictionary and they are always added on top of the content of the page.

In your code snippet, I see a method with the misleading name `AddField()`. That name is misleading because you're not adding a field. You seem to be adding content to a content stream. If that content stream is part of the content stream of a page, then it is *to be expected* and *normal* that this content is covered by the widget annotation.

It seems to me that you want to "check" the check box. Why don't you do so by filling out the form? Suppose that the name of the check box field is "cb" and the on value is "Yes", then you'd use a `PdfStamper` instance, created an `AcroFields` object (e.g. `form`) and then do something like this:

```
form.setField("cb", "Yes");
```

This should "check" the interactive check box field. See the [FillDataSheet](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=122) example for a full example.

**Important:** you need to know the *name* of the field (it won't always be "cb") and you need to know the *appearance states* of the check box (it won't always be "Yes"). You should read [chapter 6 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) for more info.